What is the name of this group-like structure?
I noticed this group-like structure popping up all over place. Below is a realization of the structure in first order rational functions.
The structure has only six elements (Edit: it's tempting to think it's some group like $S_3$, but I will later note that crucially, the three sets of elements I describe below each have a distinct additive operation only defined on that subset, and there are 4 operations in total, but the structure is still closed, and has identities and inverses).

Define $x_1$ and $x_2$ to be complementary fractions (real numbers between 0 and 1 such that $x_1+x_2=1$).

Define $y_1$ and $y_2$ to be the ratios between the complementary fractions, i.e. $y_1=\frac{x_1}{x_2}$, $y_2=\frac{x_2}{x_1}$.

Define $n_1$ and $n_2$ to be the multiplicative inverses of $x_1$ and $x_2$ respectively.


I'll include a diagram of operations between the elements later in the post, but I first want to show examples of where this structure pops up, to show why I'm motivated to understand it.
An example of this structure in probability theory is if $x_1$ and $x_2$ are probabilities of complementary events. Then $n_1$ and $n_2$ are the expected numbers of tries one needs to perform to get 1 success on the associated events. Then $y_1$ and $y_2$ are the odds (e.g. 7:1 or 19:20, if one wants to use the limited colon notation for odds).
A second example of where this occurs is if we let $x_1=\sin^2 x$, $x_2=\cos^2 x$, $n_1=\csc^2 x$, $n_2=\sec^2 x$, $y_1=\tan^2 x$, and $y_2=\cot^2 x$.
A third example is in circuit theory. If we have two elements sharing a branch or a node, then voltage or current division follows this algebra/group-thing.
If you're an electrical engineer, you might also see glimpses of this structure when dealing with BJT transistors. The parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are in fact $x_1$ and $y_1$ which is why $\beta=\frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha}$ and $\alpha=\frac{\beta}{\beta+1}$.
The reason why this structure is fascinating to me is that every element can be transformed into another element by the use of a simple first-order rational function, but of a specific form. For example $n_1=\frac{n_2}{n_2-1}$ (and this specific transformation is special in that it is an involution, along with the more obvious $1-x$ and $1/x$ in the structure). Various other interesting functions like $\frac{x}{x+1}$, $\frac{x}{1-x}$ and their one-complements and multiplicative inverses (which also simlplify to (1,0), (0,1), or (1,1) rational functions of same form, where the criteria for sameness is left vague by me, but I hope you can see the general form and which rational functions satisfy this form) can be studied in this structure and reveal cool patterns.
Here is a picture of how the structure looks like under all allowed operations:

Important Edit: PLEASE look at the diagram carefully. This does not seem associative in a way that a group would be!
Note that there are in total 4 operations, 1-, -1, +1, and 1/. Not all operations can be used on all elements. The three additive-flavor operations for example are only defined on the x's, n's, or y's respectively. However, the 1/ operation is universal in the structure. The elements neatly sort themselves into two groups of three and three groups of two based on these allowed operations.
Finally, I want to mention that the rational functions participating in transformations between the elements can be extended to all rational functions with unity coefficients, of order 1 in 2 variables $a,b$ by defining $x_1=\frac{a}{a+b}$ and $x_2=\frac{b}{a+b}$. I don't have a proof of this, this argument follows from intuition and might not be precisely correct. But this all just intrigues me so much. This is in fact the starting point from which I discovered this structure; I'm an electrical engineering student and I noticed that voltage division for example has $x_1=\frac{R_1}{R_1+R_2}$, and if one allows for negative resistance (as in active devices), you might have something like $\frac{R_a}{R_a-R_b}$ which falls into this extended structure too.
You can even further extend this structure by defining a dual set of these once-extended rational functions over additional variables 1/a and 1/b. This fits nicely into the electrical engineering picture because it actually gives a ton of intuitive insight on some relationships between resistances, conductances, and their series and parallel configurations! For example, the equivalence $\frac{R_1}{R_1+(R_2+R_3)}=\frac{G_2\|G_3}{G_1 + G_2 \| G_3}$ (where $R_i=\frac{1}{G_i}$, and $A\|B=\frac{AB}{A+B}$) can be established more intuitively in this way, if one studies the structure deeply. Note that the sum of resistances is the inverse of the parallel configuration of conductances, i.e. $\frac{1}{R_1+R_2}=G_1\|G_2=\left(\frac{1}{R_2}\right)\|\left(\frac{1}{R_2}\right)$.
Hope I demonstrated well enough why this structure is interesting to me. Does anyone know what this is?
Edit: Also, what are these extensions to the structure that I described at the end?

This is a copy of $S_3$ in the group of linear fractional transformations.

@Amateur_Algebraist not really! because it only generates rational functions of two variables with unity coefficients, such as x/(x-y), or (y+x)/(y-x), and so on (in the extended case; in the normal case, replace y with 1)

You say one of these is "idempotent" and I think you mean to say "involutory".

@ancientmathematician I guess... I'm not well versed in algebra. Oh you're right, idempotence is $a^2=a$. My bad!

@Amateur_Algebraist is surely right: the six elements you define in 1,2,3 form an $S_3$ in the linear fractional group: well studied by projective geometers.

@Amateur_Algebraist that would work except for the fact that it doesn't have two operations, the three sets of elements have different types of additive operations. Something doesn't seem right here if this was meant to be a group. How do these two things work together?

I maybe want to retract what I said. To get the $S_3$ the transformations in 2 should be $x/(x-1)$ and $(x-1)/x$ and not what you say which are the negatives of these.

Do you mean the set ${x_1,x_2,\frac{x_1}{x_2},\frac{x_2}{x_1},\frac{1}{x_1},\frac{1}{x_2}}$? What is the operation that you are considering between any two elements?

@Kan't I covered all the basics in the post but if you want me to provide you with a list of all allowed operations then: $x_1=1-x_2$, $y_1=\frac{1}{y_2}$, $x_k=\frac{1}{n_k}$, $n_k=y_j+1$, and $y_k=n_j-1$ where $k=3-j$, e.g. if k=2 then j=1 (the complementary index). The rest of the rational functions I described follow from these fundamental relationships. So it isn't just the set you described. It's that set with these operations on them (all of these really stem from the most fundamental $x_1=1-x_2$ relationship)

If you add in the opposites of all these numbers, I think you get all the fractional linear transformations that can be represented with only 0, 1 and -1. Although that's not a group.

@ancientmathematician, what is the operation amongst the six elements in 1,2,3 turning them into a group isomorphic to $S_3$?

And what is, accordingly, the unit element?

This is an open question and I think the contribution in the other answer is positive. Now I'm going to offer my perspective.
The six numbers and the twelve functions that you highlighted, together with all the possible compositions that follow the diagram including identities, form a groupoid. There really is little to check that is not immediate, since composition is associative and we always have inverses. The property that fails is closure, and not associativity as you suggested.
Furthermore, the successive composition of six arrows from the diagram starting from a point yield the identity. So there is exactly one arrow between each two objects.
There is a total of $36$ arrows. You may be tempted to call the arrow from $n_1$ to $y_2$ the same as the arrow from $n_2$ to $y_1,$ since they are represented by the same mathematical function. This is an argument against the groupoid viewpoint. However, take into account the
15 puzzle, where there are only 4 types of operation, but it's still better to call it a groupoid because not all the compositions are possible.
A final note is that if you add in the opposites to all these elements, which are related to the original elements via another involution, then all the $24$ elements in the group of fractional linear transformations that can be written using only $0,\pm 1$ appear as arrows somewhere. I still think the niceness comes from here.

Ohh.. right, it makes sense now that there's no closure but there's associativity. I think I had it flipped because I considered these transformation functions as operators themselves, and regarded the elements to have closure under the "operators" with additional imposed restrictions. But I'm glad you brought up the 15-puzzle example because I now see that the structure is very much like the 15-puzzle in that not every composition is valid, but overall there is associativity and there is still a finite number of configurations. Thank you for that!

Groupoid sounds right. I never had to work with such objects so it didn't occur to me.

What you're calling “operations” aren't operations in the algebraic sense. Relations might be the better term for them.
This looks to me like the orbit of a single number $x$ under a set of functions:

$\sigma(x) = 1-x$
$\tau(x) = \frac{1}{x}$
$\rho(x) = \frac{x}{1-x}$

Starting with a number $x_1$, we have $x_2 = \sigma(x_1)$, $y_1 = \rho(x_1)$, $y_2 = (\tau\circ\rho)(x_1)$, $n_1 = \tau(x_1)$, $n_2 = (\tau \circ \sigma)(x_1)$.
Looking at the functions instead of the numbers, we see something that begins to look like a group. The operation is composition of functions. Each of the functions is invertible. If we include the identity function $\iota(x) = x$, we notice $\sigma \circ \sigma = \tau \circ \tau = \iota$.
As commenters pointed out, these functions are called Linear fractional transformations. The set of all linear fractional transformations is a group. With rational coefficients, the group is isomorphic to $PGL_2(\mathbb{Z})$. This is the set of invertible $2\times 2$ matrices with integer entries, in which pairs of matrices that are nonzero multiples of each other are equivalent. The correspondence is $\iota = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$, $\sigma = \begin{bmatrix} -1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$, $\tau =\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$, $\rho = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ -1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$. The other functions are $\tau\rho = \begin{bmatrix}-1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ and $\tau\sigma = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$.
This is all looking very nice! There are only two groups of order six: the cyclic group and $S_3$, the symmetric group on three letters. An amateur algebraist (or even a professional one) would jump to the conclusion that we are looking at a subgroup of $PGL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ isomorphic to $S_3$...
... Until you square $\rho$. Using the matrix representation, $\rho^2 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ \color{red}{-2} & 1 \end{bmatrix}$, and that's not in our set of functions/matrices. So these six matrices don't form a finite group. We can consider the group they generate, but since $\rho^k = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ -k & 1 \end{bmatrix}$, that group won't be finite.

I don't think we want to square $\rho$, I think you want $\rho$ to be $\frac{x}{x-1}$, then it's an involution and it will remain in the "group". I have two problems with it being a group though. I think the structure is more restricted. You don't want to, for example compose "x+1" (which is composed of the basic three elements) with "1-x" (a basic element itself) because that's not a valid composition in the structure (look at the diagram again carefully). One last qualm I have with it being a group, I don't see associativity working here.

Going off my last reply, yeah matrices are in a group that provides associativity, but given my criticism of the fact that not everything in the set can be composed with each other, I start to doubt that it really is the group you're describing here. And I still don't see associativity working in my restricted structure.

@KKZiomek The trouble is that some of us still can't fathom what structure you are talking about.

@ancientmathematician I mean the diagram is all you really need. I really don't know how else to explain it. Let me try this way. Take the 2nd example of the structure from the post. The structure has closure over the squares of the six trig functions. But to remain within the six squares of trig functions, you can't add 1 to $\sin^2 x$. You can, however add 1 to $\tan^2 x$ or $\cot^2 x$ and you'll get $\sec^2 x$ and $\csc^2 x$ respectively. This is what I'm talking about when I say certain transformations only apply to certain subsets of the elements in the structure

I mean just take the squares of the six trig functions and play around with what you can do to them in order to remain within the subset, you'll find that you can always invert them (apply 1/x), but you can only subtract 1, for example, if you have a csc/sec (n in my notation) and that will give you cot/tan (squared of course). That's what I mean when I say you can't always apply the 4 operations on each of the 4 elements. Hence, there is no associativity. I mean, the diagram has it all, and you have the trig example to play with. What else do I need to explain?

A diagram like that might be considered to represent a groupoid with six objects and exactly one arrow between each pair of objects.

No doubt it's my fault. :-(

@Keplerto this is getting closer. I also found the idea of a "Loop" in the Quasi-Group wikipedia which has inverses, identities, and closure. I'll look at it later and see. But your suggestion also looks good, I just don't know how to verify

@ancientmathematician I mean it's not anyone's fault. I tried my best to explain what I mean, granted this is a very strange thing that no one ever really looks at. I do feel really annoyed though that people post answers saying confidently that it is what it's not just because it looks similar to something they're familiar with, but don't actually check if their answer fits all criteria in the question. I mean I get it that everyone wants to have points on this website, but still, read the goddamn question in whole if you post, don't make assumptions and don't take all details for granted...

I am not sure that this is an answer to the question as set, but it is too long for a comment. Like @Matthew Leingang I think this is really to do with the Symmetric Group    on three letters which occurs as a subgroup of the linear fractional group. But to make that work you need to be prepared to slightly adapt your configuration!
I think that one should not look at your $\frac{x_1}{x_2}$ and $\frac{x_2}{x_1}$ but rather at the negatives of these, namely $-\frac{x_1}{x_2}=\frac{x_1}{x_1-1}$ and $-\frac{x_2}{x_1}=\frac{x_1-1}{x_1}$.
Then we have the following transformations (as @Matthew points out in his answer and as was mentioned in the original comments)
$$
\sigma: t\mapsto 1-t,\ \ \sigma^2: t\mapsto t
$$
and
$$
 \tau: t\mapsto \frac{1}{t}, \ \ \ \tau^2: t\mapsto t. 
$$
Then
$$
\sigma\circ\tau: t\mapsto \frac{t-1}{t},\ \ \ (\sigma\circ\tau)^2: t\mapsto \frac{t}{1-t},\ \ \ (\sigma\circ\tau)^3: t\mapsto t.
$$
That is, we have a little group of transformations,  $\{e, \sigma\tau,(\sigma\tau)^2, \sigma, \tau, \tau\sigma\tau\}\simeq S_3$
Now "the diagram" (with the new definition of $y_1,y_2$ using the negatives of yours) is just a picture of a general orbit of this group and how the transformations move the points around.
There are a couple of special cases, though: the harmonic case when the values of the six points collapse into three pairs, and the equianharmonic case when the values of the six points collapse into two triplets. For more about these you need to consult old-fashioned books on projective geometry.

Ok, thanks for taking the time. The idea you mention in the end is interesting. I did note to myself that if x=1/2 then it collapses into two points and if x=0 then it collapses into three points (if you take the projective real line), but I wasn't aware of the terminology, so thanks for that. I'll see what the implications for the y's being the negative of each other are later today. It's possibly still not precisely what I need, but it's the closest anyone has gotten here

When $x=\frac12$ it should collapse into three points $\frac12, 2, -1$. The other collapse occurs in the complex case only, $x=-\omega$ where $\omega$ is a cube root of unity.
